# Not a single group function

Tags: oracle, aggregate-functions

This query is not showing anything at all.  I want results only those ORDERNO which match in the sub-query.

```
SELECT SUM(STY.NQTY * STY.NUNITPRICE   
             / 1000) AS ORDERAMOUNT,
    (SELECT SUM(TBLORDERSTYLE.NQTY * TBLORDERSTYLE.NUNITPRICE/1000) FROM TBLORDER
    INNER JOIN TBLORDERSTYLE
    ON TBLORDER.CORDERNO = TBLORDERSTYLE.CORDERNO
    WHERE TBLORDER.CLCNO LIKE '%MR#%' AND
    TBLORDER.CORDERNO = ORD.CORDERNO
    GROUP BY ORD.CORDERNO) AS K
          FROM TBLORDER ORD INNER JOIN   
          TBLORDERSTYLE STY ON    
          ORD.CORDERNO = STY.CORDERNO
          where (ORD.NPOSTFLAG = '1') AND   
           (ORD.NCANCEL = '0') AND
    ORD.NPAYMODE = '1'  AND  
          (ORD.DPICONFIRMDATE  BETWEEN    
          TO_DATE('01-JUL-2012')AND TO_DATE('31-JUL-2012'))
```

Comment: Please turn your capslock off, we don't like people shouting around here.

Comment: instead of giving us your not-working SQL, please supply the sample data in the tables involved and an example of the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite clear: you don't have a GROUP BY clause.  Whenever we mix aggregating functions like SUM() with non-aggregated columns we need to include the static columns in a GROUP BY clause.

In you code the static column is `K`.  Yes it is derived from an aggregation but that is in a sub-query, and so it counts as a non-aggregating column.

The way to solve thi sis to move the sub-query into a common table expression (what Oracle calls subquery factoring), which makes it easy to reference the column more than once.  The use of the WITH cluase is covered in the Oracle SQL Reference.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2077142).

```
with cte as (SELECT ORD.CORDERNO
                   , SUM(TBLORDERSTYLE.NQTY * TBLORDERSTYLE.NUNITPRICE/1000) as k
    FROM TBLORDER
    INNER JOIN TBLORDERSTYLE
    ON TBLORDER.CORDERNO = TBLORDERSTYLE.CORDERNO
    WHERE TBLORDER.CLCNO LIKE '%MR#%' AND
    TBLORDER.CORDERNO = ORD.CORDERNO
    GROUP BY ORD.CORDERNO)
SELECT SUM(STY.NQTY * STY.NUNITPRICE   
             / 1000) AS ORDERAMOUNT,
      cte.K
          FROM cte inner join
          TBLORDER ORD on ord.orderno = k.orderno
          INNER JOIN TBLORDERSTYLE STY ON STY.CORDERNO  = k.orderno
          where (ORD.NPOSTFLAG = '1') AND   
           (ORD.NCANCEL = '0') AND
           ORD.NPAYMODE = '1'  AND  
          (ORD.DPICONFIRMDATE  BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JUL-2012')AND TO_DATE('31-JUL-2012'))
group by cte.k
```

It's highly likely that this is not the actual logic you need.  You did not include any explanation of the business rules you're trying to implement so I have just made a guess at how to join the sub-query with the main query.

Comment: i have edited your answer it gives an error on line 13 i want to match corderno with the corderno of the subquery.

Comment: ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: i am new to oracle to subquery factoring is a ghost